# Basic regression example not fitting

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to convert a code sample from a Tensorflow 1.3.x course to Tensorflow 2.x.
Why is this fit so wildly off?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf

np.random.seed(101)
tf.random.set_seed(101)
x_data = np.linspace(0, 10, 100) + np.random.uniform(-1.5, 1.5, 100)
y_label = np.linspace(0, 10, 100) + np.random.uniform(-1.5, 1.5, 100)

# y = mx + b
m = tf.Variable(np.random.random())
b = tf.Variable(np.random.random())

@tf.function
def forward(x):
    return m * x + b

@tf.function
def cost():
    y_model = forward(tf.cast(x_data, dtype=tf.float32))
    error = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_model - y_label))
    return error

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.001)
opt.minimize(cost, var_list=[m, b])

print(m)
print(b)

x_test = np.linspace(-1, 11, 10)
y_pred_plot = m.value() * x_test + b.value()

plt.plot(x_test, y_pred_plot, 'r')
plt.plot(x_data, y_label, '*')
```

[image: regression plot]

Comment: LR can be very low, try something like `0.015`

Comment: The SGD's learning rate seems to have an effect on the alignment. I tested with learning_rate=0.012. The aligment is better.

Comment: Yes that definitely gives a better fit. Why is this so? Surely the optimiser will run until convergence or does it have set convergence criteria? Do I need to specify number of iterations somewhere? Sorry for all the questions

Comment: With higher LR you took bigger steps towards to minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`minimize` computes the gradients(using [GradTape](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape)) and applies gradients by `apply_gradients` method. So you are basically, computing the gradients and optimizing for one iteration.

You can use:

```
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.001)

for _ in range(100):
  opt.minimize(cost, var_list=[m, b])
  if _ % 20 == 0:
    print('Error is %f m is now %f and b is now %f' %(tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(m*x_data+b - y_label)),m,b))
```

This will give:

```
Error is 9.157428 m is now 0.487972 and b is now 0.205907
Error is 1.821393 m is now 0.844750 and b is now 0.260651
Error is 1.409622 m is now 0.929036 and b is now 0.275121
Error is 1.386336 m is now 0.948780 and b is now 0.280034
Error is 1.384849 m is now 0.953240 and b is now 0.282669
```

[image]

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for this answer. There is SO much fragmented information across versions floating around it is incredibly difficult to get a straight answer.